# NVS vector stream tool

Tags: arctoolbox

Is there any document for using NVS vector stream tool? I found difficulties when using it for my data (shape file). It says  "Streams Layer must contain a TNODE_ field denoting the arc's (stream's) destination node". The question is how to calculate TNODE?

Regards,

Anas

Answer (score 2):

For the NVS Vector stream tool to work, your input data needs a TNODE and FNODE, which indicate the NODE id of each ends of each feature.

The best way to generate these nodes, is to convert your data to an ArcINFO coverage and build the coverage, and then get it back to your original format.

If you want a programmatic way, please have a look at: [How to populate From Node and To Node fields for a polyline feature class? (ArcGIS 10)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22042/how-to-populate-from-node-and-to-node-fields-for-a-polyline-feature-class-arcg)